# AngularJS/Cordova: How can I get values in my factory after deviceready?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cordova, angularjs-factory

I am trying to use the Cordova Device plugin to get info about the device the user is using. The docs say it can only be called AFTER the `deviceready` function, so in my `.run` function I have the following:

```
.run(function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        console.log(device);
    }

 //more functions below
```

This is working great, I see the device object in the console, however what I really want is to use the device object inside a factory that will sometimes get called BEFORE the `deviceready` event.

So my question is how can I get make device object available to my factory when it becomes available? I want something like the below code

```
angular.module('myapp.services.myFactory', [])

.factory('MyFactory', function($q) {

    function getDevice () {
        //if the deviceready event happend and I can access the device object set to variable
        return device;
    }

    return {
        getDeviceInfo: function getDeviceInfo() {
            return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
                if (getDevice()) {
                    //do something with the device object 
                } else {
                   //do something without device object
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to leverage `.run` here - you should be able to execute everything inside `deviceready` including your module and factory definitions. Just wrap everything in with this event. I also don't believe you need `$q` to resolve any promises either. Observe the following simplified pattern...

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    // guessing your dependency architecture
    angular
        .module('myapp', ['myapp.services'])
        .module('myapp.services', ['myapp.services.myFactory'])
        .module('myapp.services.myFactory', [])
        .factory('MyFactory', function() {

            function withDevice() {
                /*...*/
            }

            function withoutDevice() {
                /*...*/
            }

            return {
                // turnary. device always available to examine at this point
                'getDeviceInfo': device ? withDevice : withoutDevice
            }
        });
}

document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
```